# Decrypt ApplePay Token with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encryption, npm, openssl, applepay

I would like to decrypt an ApplePay token in an environment where I can get NPM packages.  There are several repos to do this, but not in JavaScript.

For Ruby https://github.com/spreedly/gala

I'd like to port this, but I'm unsure of the equivalent OpenSSL calls in JavaScript.

```
OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-256-gcm").decrypt
OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(Base64.decode64(ephemeral_public_key))
OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
Digest::SHA256.new
```

Cab someone point me to an NPM package and what functions are equivalent?

Comment: If anyone is interested there's quite a bit of this done here: https://github.com/sidimansourjs/applepay-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to cobble together some projects and get a working decryption example in JS.

https://github.com/inturbidus/applepay-token